# ASP.NET MVCでAreaごとにContentやScriptを設定したい

Tags: .net, c#, asp.net, razor

ASP.NET MVC 5(Visual Stodio 2013 Update 4)環境で開発しています。

Content(cssなど)やScript(Javascriptなど)は通常Project直下にフォルダを作成して展開すると思います。
これを各Areaごとに配置することは可能でしょうか。

私が試した環境では、

Area
　-hogehoge
　　-Content
　　　-Style.css

と配置しましたが、

@Url.Content(~/hogehoge/Content/Style.css)
も
@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(~/hogehoge/Content/)
もファイルが参照できなくエラーとなってしまいました。

Comment: 具体的なエラーの情報を載せておくと回答者の参考になると思います。

Answer (score 3):

Areaではなく、Area**s** ではないですか？

---

### Url.Contentで参照する

以下の構成で  
[image: SolutionExplorer]

`Style.css`は以下として

```
body {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

@Url.Contentで直接指定する場合、例えば`_Layout.cshtml`でlinkタグを用意するには以下の様に指定できます。
Layoutを使わなくても同様に指定できると思います。

```html
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Areas/hogehoge/Content/Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

[image: AffectedPage]  
**スタイルが反映されたページ**

### Styles.Render

ただ、なるべくバンドルを追加して `@Styles.Render` で追加する方がいいでしょう。
それには以下の様にします。

まず、`App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`を開きます。

[image: BundleConfig.cs]

以下のbundles.Addを追加します。

```cs
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Areas/hogehoge/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Areas/hogehoge/Content/Style.css"
    ));
```

先ほど追加した `<link href="@Url.Content`の行を以下の様に変更します。

```
@Styles.Render("~/Areas/hogehoge/Content/css")
```

スタイルを追加した場合はBundles.AddのIncludeの引数を増やしてください。
（すでにあると思われる`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").`が参考になると思います）

### 補足

ちなみに`BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl(`に関してもたとえば

```
<!--
   @System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Areas/hogehoge/Content/css") 
-->
```

としておくとHTMLは以下の様に出力されますので

```
<!--
    /Areas/hogehoge/Content/css?v=yhOQn7MXW55kWVM6x07Bf3QlCaPBa716IIGs-NlMwiA1 
-->
```

きちんと対象のURLが取れると思います。